# Изменение отображения chart doughnut

Tags: c#, winforms

Как можно изменить chart doughnut ,чтобы он выглядел как на этой картинке?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
По умолчанию он выглядит как полный круг, на картинке же только половина круга

Comment: Что за библиотека используется для графиков?

Comment: стандартный chart doughnut в winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нашел у MSChart такой настройки. Можно схитрить: добавить значение, так чтобы оно занимало нижний полукруг, затем присвоить ему прозрачный цвет.

Чтобы значение занимало нижний полукруг оно должно идти первым по порядку и быть равно сумме остальных значений:

```
//значения
int[] values = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

//график
var series = new Series() { ChartArea = "ChartArea1", ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut };
//считаем сумму
int sum = values.Sum();
//задаем первое значение с прозрачным цветом
var firstPoint = new DataPoint(0, sum) { Color = Color.Transparent };
series.Points.Add(firstPoint);
//добавляем остальные значения
foreach (var item in values)
{
    series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, item));
}
chart1.Series.Add(series);
```

Получится что-то вроде:

[image: График]

Если скрыть легенду и поиграться с расположением можно добиться нужного отображения.